# Livewire's wire:transition affects correctly updating a component with child components

Tags: transition, laravel-livewire

I have a fairly easy set up, where want to show a user a list of created items. When there are no items, a message is shown to create the first one. To smoothen the UI I'm using `wire:transition`. However, when I add `wire:transition` the component updating goes south.

## simplified structure

```
@forelse($items as $item)
  Test... {{ $item->title }}<br/><!-- this is shown, so $items is correctly updated -->
  <livewire:item-detail wire:key="{{ $item->id }}" :$item/><!-- this doesn't render at all, due to wire:transition -->
@empty
  <div wire:transition>
    <img src="..."/> <!-- nice illustration -->
    <p>Create your first item, since you have none at the moment</p>
    <button x-data x-on:click="..">Add item</button><!-- opens modal component -->
  </div>
@endforelse
```

## simplified item-detail

```
<div>
  Title = {{ $item->title }}<br/>
</div>
```

Now, when I remove `wire:transition` from the @empty part, everything works like a charm. I've tried fiddling around with wire:transition in the @forelse part, and in the child component root . But to no avail.

What am I overlooking?